# move azure SQL database from resource group to another one

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-group

I moved my SQL server and SQL database from one resource group to another one.

The SQL database exists in the SQL server with Online status. When I try to go on it. I got the following error:
"This resource was not found, it may have been deleted. /subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group name}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{sql server name}/databases/{database-name}".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. You may have to wait a few hours and everything will be fine again. Meanwhile you will keep getting those "This resource was not found, it may have been deleted. [...]" error messages. Sometimes you may have to wait more than just a few hours, to be sincere you may have to wait a day, but everything will be fine again.

Comment: I waited for one day then I got the database name again.

Comment: Yes, it takes sometime for the move operation to finish. I am glad your resources are OK.